# Spring MongoDB - Why unique index are also applied to embedded document?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, unique-constraint

I have a document A with a unique index and another document B which embed A. When I try to persist 2 documents B with same document A in them, I get a dup key error. Why? Shouldn't the unique index be ensured **only** in the collection where it is specified?

**A.java**

```
@Document(collection = "docsA") 
public class A {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)  
    private String name;

    private B embed;
}
```

**B.java**

```
@Document(collection="docsB")
public class B {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)  
    private String name;
}
```

Persisting ops:

```
B b = new B();
b.setName("BName1");
docsBRepository.save(b);

A a1 = new A();
a1.setName("AName1");
a1.setB(b);
docsARepository.save(a1); // stored

A a2 = new A();
a2.setName("AName2");
a2.setB(b);
docsARepository.save(a2); // dup key error
```

Comment: But it **is** implemented in the collection. An "embedded" document is "part of" the source collection and not actually stored in another collection. Thus it rarely makes any sense to have a "unique" property when the data is embedded in the array, unless you really mean it. So you are either confused in thinking the data is stored somewhere else, or you want *"unique items in the array of each document"*, for which there are other programmatic solutions that do not involve indexes. Unique indexes **always** apply "collection wide".

Comment: I forgot to mention that each document is stored in its own collection (I just edited the post). That's why I need unique index in each document. At the same time I need that doc B is embedded in doc A , but without ensuring it's unique index.

Answer (score 2):

I do a test from my side with your docs and using this config.

```
public interface DocsARepository extends MongoRepository<A,Long>{}
public interface DocsBRepository extends MongoRepository<B,Long>{}
```

This spring config

```
<mongo:mongo id="mongo" />
<mongo:repositories base-package="spring.mongodb.repositories"/>
```

And this test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "spring.xml")
public class Launcher {

    @Autowired
    DocsBRepository docsBRepository;
    @Autowired
    DocsARepository docsARepository;

   @Test
   public void test1(){

        B b = new B();
        b.setName("BName1");
        b = docsBRepository.save(b);

        A a1 = new A();
        a1.setName("AName1");
        a1.setB(b);
       docsARepository.save(a1); // stored

        A a2 = new A();
        a2.setName("AName2");
        a2.setB(b);
        docsARepository.save(a2); //Dont get any error but record is not inserted
    }

}
```

After running the test I found that the object a2 is not being inserted in the database, not really sure what happend this behaviour but if I add @Reference over the private B field, this works like a charm.

```
> db.docsA.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5717acb720e54e20a4d96517"),
        "_class" : "com.koitoer.spring.mongodb.domain.A",
        "name" : "AName1",
        "b" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5717acb720e54e20a4d96516"),
                "name" : "BName1"
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5717acb720e54e20a4d96518"),
        "_class" : "com.koitoer.spring.mongodb.domain.A",
        "name" : "AName2",
        "b" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5717acb720e54e20a4d96516"),
                "name" : "BName1"
        }
}
```

My advice you try using in Class A

```
@Reference
private B b;
```

Using

```
<org.mongodb.version>1.5.5.RELEASE</org.mongodb.version>
<org.mongodb.driver>3.0.0-beta3</org.mongodb.driver>
<spring-framework.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
```

Adding this working example in [github](https://github.com/koitoer/mongo-db-support/tree/develop/src/main/java/com/koitoer/spring/mongodb)

Comment: The issue is with compound indexes too. `@CompoundIndexes({    @CompoundIndex(name = "a_name_b_name", def = "{'name': 1, embed.name': -1}", unique=true)})` also throws dup key.

Comment: Paste the code for your insert statements pls or the items you are trying to save I think then a dup is there

Comment: I've edited the post with the persisting code example.

Comment: I've added a nother response, I do it by myself and not duplicate error found but the second A record was not inserted until I add the Reference annotation

Comment: So using `@Reference` is the record inserted correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it in annotation based way, but you can achieve it programmatically, by adding such Spring's @Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@DependsOn("mongoTemplate")
public class CollectionsConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initIndexes() {
        mongoTemplate.indexOps("docsB") // so index is applied only to "docsB" collection
            .ensureIndex(
                new Index().on("name", Sort.Direction.ASC)
        );
    }
}
```